# Find area of irregular polygon

Tags: geometry, area, polygons

I am currently taking the Scottish Mathematical Council's [Mathematical Challenge 2016/17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ2l3.png). I am unable to solve problem S4.

For this problem, I need to find the area of this irregular polygon.

[image: SMC Mathematical Challenge 2016/17 S4]

I have attempted to split it up into smaller shapes (triangles and rectangles) but am still unable to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

Show that the right vertex and the left vertex are at the same height, and that the top vertex is $\frac12$ above them.
Then we can split the shape into

- a $1\times 1$ square
- a right triangle with legs $1$ and $\sqrt 3$
- a triangle with base $1+\sqrt 3$ and height $\frac12$

Answer (score 0):

Using the law of sine and the law of cosine, you should be able to solve for some angles and sides.

$$S = \frac{1}{2}(1)(1) + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}\sin(75) + \frac{1}{2}(1)(2)\sin(60)$$